# Need help understanding a step in a proof about modules over PIDs

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated, cyclic-decomposition

This is Chapter 3, Theorem 7.3 in *Algebra* by W. Adkins & S. Weintraub (GTM).
It's about the uniqueness of the cyclic decomposition for finitely generated modules over a PID. I highlighted the exact step that I don't understand.
How the negation of $\langle p \rangle \supseteq \operatorname{Ann}(z_i)$ implies that sum of ideals?

[image: Theorem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a P.I.D., irreducible elements generate maximal ideals,. On the other hand, any proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal. So, if $\operatorname{Ann}(z_i)$ is not contained in $(p)$, which is maximal, the only ideal which contains both is $R$.

Comment: Sir, is it true that the proof of "irreducible elements generate maximal ideals" requires Zorn's lemma?

Comment: I really don't know.It sometimes happens that in some courses, they use Zorn's lemma because it yields short proofs, but it is not always necessary. For   instance, one proves the existence of maximal ideals with Zorn's lemma, but if I remember well, it can be proved without it for noetherian rings.

Comment: Do you think it's possible in this case to find explicitly the way to rewrite every element $r \in R$ as the sum of elements in the required ideals?

Comment: Sorry. I understand those facts, but I don't get why they imply $\langle p \rangle + \operatorname{Ann}(z_i) = R$.

Comment: Because if it weren't equal to $R$, it would be contained in a maximal ideal, which can only be $(p)$. This is contrary to the hypothesis on $\operatorname{Ann}(z_i)$.

Comment: For your previous question, once you've found $a\in R$ and $b\in$\operatorname{Ann}(z_i)$ such that $\; ap+b=1$, it's immediate: $r=r\cdot 1=rap+rb$.

Comment: Right$.$ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a PID, the ideal generated by a prime element is a maximal ideal.